# dump weights of cnn in json using keras

Tags: json, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to use the dumped weights and model architecture in other framework for testing.

I know that:

- `model.get_config()` can give the configuration of the model
- `model.to_json` returns a representation of the model as a JSON string, but that the representation does not include the weights, only the architecture
- `model.save_weights(filepath)` saves the weights of the model as a HDF5 file

I want to save the architecture as well as weights in a json file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keras does not have any built-in way to export the weights to JSON.

**Solution 1:**

For now you can easily do it by iterating over the weights and saving it to the JSON file.

```
weights_list = model.get_weights()
```

will return a list of all weight tensors in the model, as Numpy arrays.

Then, all you have to do next is to iterate over this list and write to the file:

```
for i, weights in enumerate(weights_list):
    writeJSON(weights)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import json
weights_list = model.get_weights()
print json.dumps(weights_list.tolist())
```

Comment: I had to do `json.dumps(numpy.array(weights_list).tolist())` because of `'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'` error.