# How can I convert an HDF5 file to a JSON and back?

Tags: json, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, hdf5

I am currently trying to store my deep learning models from tensorflow and keras in a graph database called ArangoDB. Like most object databases, ArangoDB requires the files to be in JSON. I may be willing to switch to HDFS, but either way Tensorflow and Keras insist on using proprietary HDF5 format from the HDF5 group to store their weights.

How can I convert these using python to a JSON format to be stored in the DB and how can I convert them back to be loaded again in tensorflow?

Answer (score -3):

https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/ shows how you could save models in JSON with keras. Once you have the file in JSON format, you can persist that. 
The following does not store a model but stores TFX artifacts in ArangoDB.
https://github.com/arangoml/arangopipe/blob/master/arangopipe/tests/TFX/tfx_metadata_integration.ipynb

Comment: This does not answer the question. I need to store the weights not just the architecture. The link you provided is just a guide on how to generate the architecture json and the heft file that I'm currently stuck with.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971649/dump-weights-of-cnn-in-json-using-keras  ?